# ReferenceError: NReco PivotTable Extensions is not defined

Tags: pivottable.js

I am trying for sorting functionality in Pivot Table.I have created Pivot Table by using pivotTable.js . Using nrecopivot.js , trying for sorting but i am getting ReferenceError: NReco PivotTable Extensions is not defined .
Any help?
I am creating pivot table using this code.

```
var nrecoPivotExt = new NRecoPivotTableExtensions({
                drillDownHandler: function (dataFilter) {

                    var filterParts = [];
                    for (var k in dataFilter) {
                        filterParts.push(k+"="+dataFilter[k]);
                    }

                }
            });
            var stdRendererNames = ["Table","Table Barchart","Heatmap","Row Heatmap","Col Heatmap"];
            var wrappedRenderers = $.extend( {}, $.pivotUtilities.renderers);
            $.each(stdRendererNames, function() {
                var rName = this;
                wrappedRenderers[rName] = nrecoPivotExt.wrapTableRenderer(wrappedRenderers[rName]);
            });
            var pivotRepName = "pivotData.csv";
            var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;
                $.get(pivotRepName , function(mps) {
                    $("#Result").pivotUI($.csv.toArrays(mps), {
                         renderers: $.extend(
                                 $.pivotUtilities.renderers, 
                                 $.pivotUtilities.gchart_renderers, 
                                 $.pivotUtilities.d3_renderers,
                                 $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
                                 ),
                         renderers: wrappedRenderers,
                         rendererOptions: { sort: { direction : "desc", column_key : [ 2014 ]} },
                         rendererName: "Table",
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and fixed it.now its working fine. My build didn't copy the nrecpivot.js file into my war location.That was the issue.